# loadreport fails when called from within C# class library

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports-2008

I have created a class library for use from Classic ASP. The load report fails (see trace)

```
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() 
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) 
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename) 
at test.crystalLib.generate_pdf() in D:\wwwroot\test\Crystal\test\test\crystalLib.cs:line 27
```

But the same code works when called from .cs file or an .ashx file.

is there any property that i should change in the class library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave write permission for iis user to windows temp folder. this solved the issue.